# Symfony2 routing with annotations

Tags: symfony, annotations

I am trying to define my routes using annotations in symfony2. My Bundle name is PatentBundle. But I am getting an error of

```
No route found for "GET /portfolio/
```

My app/config/routing.yml

```
MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:
resource: "@MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /
defaults:  { _controller: "MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:Default:index" }
```

My portfolio controller looks like

```
<?php
 namespace MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Controller;

 use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\Log;

 use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UserPatent;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
 use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
 use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\SvPatents;
 use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PmPortfolios;
 use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UmUsers;
 use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Form\PatentType;
 use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PmPatentgroups;
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
 use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Util\SecurityHelper;
 use Exception;

/**
 * Portfolio controller.
 * @Route("/portfolio")
*/
class PortfolioController extends Controller {

/**
 * Index action.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="portfolio")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template("MunichInnovationGroupBundle:Portfolio:show.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
      // method code goes here
    }
```

Comment: Do you get "/portfolio/" route in router:debug? Or just "/portfolio"? Route "/portfolio/" is different from "/portfolio".

Comment: What append without the trailing slash? `/porfolio` ?

Comment: It gives the same error on both

Answer (score 9):

```
# app/config/routing.yml

MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:

    resource: "@MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

The controller should have:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
```

Comment: I want to import the whole controller directory not only the default controller. I am getting error on the portfolio controller

Comment: Thanks for the "The controller should have:" section. You need to include all of those, even if they are not being used.

Comment: is there any way to specify @Method at class level ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the developement environment check you import the routing.yml in routing_dev.yml:

```
# app/config/routing_dev.yml

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

Comment: Your code whould work... As suggested by Simone Demo Gentili, you should see all your active routes using `app/console router:debug` what is the result?

Comment: I checked it through aap/console and I have two bundles 1 is Bundle and the other is PatentBundle. Bundle also has portfolio route and its path is v1/portfolio, I want to make the PatentBundle routes work not the others.

Comment: So you have to understand why your route is `v1/portfolio` and not `/portfolio`. This didn't appear in the code you post.

Comment: yeah i just run the command u provided and it showed me that the path for portfolio rout is v1/portfolio not portfolio. but how can I use Patentbundle routes.

Answer (score -2):

Add following code in your bundle `MunichInnovationGroup/PatentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`

```
_admin_emailTemplate:
    pattern: admin/emailTemplate
    defaults: {_controller: DashboardEmailTemplateBundle:Default:index }
requirements: { _method: GET | POST }
```

Above is just an example of bundle. You only have to post bold text "requirements".